# how to prevent sudden jerk in scroll triggered fixed nav bar after some scrolling is done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to html and jquery.and sorry for poorly written code.i have designed a scroll triggered nav bar which fixes after some scrolling is done using jquery like on w3school.com.but there is some glitch,if you scroll using mouse then there is a bit delay or a little jerk to say before the nav bar is fixed,it is observed while scrolling steadily.i hope u people have understood wat i want to say.
i want to achieve smoothness like this:-http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

Jquery code is written in the last:-

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

 <head><title>home</title>
 <style>       <!-- css css css css css css-->
*{box-sizing:border-box}
 body{margin:0}
    div.header{margin:0
       padding:0
       max-width:100%;
       height:auto;

       background-color:black;

         }

      img.header{width:100%;
                  display:block;
               }

      nav.fixed{position:fixed;top:0;width:100%;z-index:10}
      nav{background-color:#4CAF50;z-index:10}

      nav a{display:inline-block;
            text-decoration:none;
            color:white;
           padding:15px 25px;
          margin:0;margin-right:-4px; transition-duration: 0.4s;
          }    
       nav a:hover{background-color:white;
        color:black;
        }      

         div.sidebar{
                   width:200px;
                    float:left;
                    height:700px;
                    background:gray;
                    padding:5px;
                    overflow-y:scroll;
                    }
                  div.sidebarFixed{position:fixed;top:38px;}            
                div.section{width:65%;position:relative;left:200px;
                  height:2000px;
                background:#f2f2f2;}            



      </style>     <!--css css css css css css css-->

     <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">             </script>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
  </head>


  <body>

        <div class="header">
        <img class="header" src="images/top.jpg" alt="journal of advance      science & environment" />

      </div>
     <nav class="nv" id="n">

         <a href="#">menu one</a>
         <a href="#">menu two</a>
          <a href="#">menu three</a>
          <a href="#">menu one</a>
           <a href="#">menu one</a>



      </nav>    


     <div class="section">

     </div>
       <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function(){

     var navOffset=jQuery("nav").offset().top;
    jQuery("nav").wrap('<div class="placeholder" ></div>');
    jQuery("div.placeholder").height(jQuery("nav").outerHeight());


    jQuery(window).scroll(function(){

    var scrollPos=jQuery(window).scrollTop();

    if(scrollPos >= navOffset){

        jQuery("nav").addClass("fixed");            
        jQuery(".sidebar").addClass("sidebarFixed");

    }else{
        jQuery("nav").removeClass("fixed");
        jQuery(".sidebar").removeClass("sidebarFixed");
     }

     });    

     })
    </script>



     </body>


    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is really any problem with what you have. I did find a couple syntax issues with your css (missing semi-colons and what not) and after fixing those it seems to be working fine on my end. The other thing I did was separate out your styles from inline into an external sheet, which made it a lot more readable.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

     var navOffset=jQuery("nav").offset().top;
     jQuery("nav").wrap('<div class="placeholder" ></div>');
     jQuery("div.placeholder").height(jQuery("nav").outerHeight());


     jQuery(window).scroll(function(){

     var scrollPos=jQuery(window).scrollTop();

     if(scrollPos >= navOffset){

         jQuery("nav").addClass("fixed");            
         jQuery(".sidebar").addClass("sidebarFixed");

     }else{
         jQuery("nav").removeClass("fixed");
         jQuery(".sidebar").removeClass("sidebarFixed");
      }

      });    

     })
```

```css
*{
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
 moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 ms-box-sizing:border-box;
 box-sizing:border-box
}
 
body{
 margin:0
}
div.header{
 margin:0;
    padding:0;
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background-color:black;
}
img.heaer{
 width:100%;
    display:block;
}
nav.fixed{
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 width:100%;
 z-index:10
}
nav{
 background-color:#4CAF50;
 z-index:10
}
nav a{
 display:inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    padding:15px 25px;    
 margin-right:-4px; 
 transition-duration: 0.4s;
}    
nav a:hover{
 background-color:white;
    color:black;
}      
div.sidebar{
 width:200px;
    float:left;
    height:700px;
    background:gray;
    padding:5px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
div.sidebarFixed{
 position:fixed;
 top:38px;
}            
div.section{
 width:65%;
 position:relative;
 left:200px;
    height:2000px;
    background:#f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <title>home</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">             </script>

 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
</head>


<body>

 <div class="header">
  <img class="header" src="images/top.jpg"        alt="journal of advance      science & environment" />

 </div>
 <nav class="nv" id="n">
  <a href="#">menu one</a>
  <a href="#">menu two</a>
  <a href="#">menu three</a>
  <a href="#">menu one</a>
  <a href="#">menu one</a>
 </nav>    
 <div class="section">

 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comparing it to w3schools it seems to work about the same. I would think about restructuring some of your markup though. Particularly with your nav list.

Comment: well thanx a lot for help